# How to approximate $\sqrt[3]{x}$ when $x$ is rational number

Tags: polynomials, approximation

One wants to approximate the real value of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ when $x$ is rational number. One want to approximate to two decimal digits.

Is there any way to do this quickly?

Comment: Did you study Taylor polynomial? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_and_convergence

Comment: Got it. thanks.

Comment: Another way is to use Newton's method.

Comment: Another way is to use a calculator.

Comment: Another way is to compute the continued fraction.